# Could not Add Platform Android using cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I'm first time using phonegap/cordova, i work on windows8 x64, i've problem when i want to add platform Android on my project. I got this message when i execute the command `cordova platform add android`

```
D:\SoftDev\PhoneDev\Cordova\SiPemel>cordova platform add android
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
Error: Failed to fetch platform android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token C
Cannot GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
```

could someone here to help me to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this is a cache problem of cordova. Clean the cordova cache and try to add the platform again. To clear the cache type this in your console:

```
rm -rf ~/.cordova
```

Comment: Is there a Windows equivalent for this command?? I'm using Win7 and there's no ".cordova" object on my drive